# How to disable minimize and maximize option in chrome extension window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, window, content-script

```
function showActivityDashboard() {
    console.log("Showing ActivityDashboard Screen");
    const targetURL = 'pages/MyDashboardForm.html';
    const w = 475;
    const h = 270;
    var left = parseInt((screen.width / 2) - (w / 2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.height / 2) - (h / 2));
    var promise = getTabId(targetURL);
    promise.then(function (target) {

        if (target != undefined) {
            chrome.windows.update(target.id, { focused: true })
        }
        else {
            chrome.windows.create(
                {
                    'url': targetURL,
                    'focused': true,
                    'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top,
                    'type': 'popup'

                },
                function (window) {
                    chrome.windows.update(window.id, {}, function onUpdated() {
                        console.log('');
                    });

                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

In this way i am creating window in my chrome extension[image] I want to disable the minimize and maximize option how to do that ? Is that possible? I tried 'resizable: false' in 'chrome.windows.create' but its not working.

Comment: There's no way to do it via extension API, but you can try using the new [document-in-picture](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/document-picture-in-picture/).